# alert / Confirm fires multiple times on bootsrap modal using fullCalendar eventClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

i'm using the function `eventClick` on `fullcalendar`and i have the following problem, whenever i click at an event a modal is opening and i can edit this specific event, and when i click on save (with another onclick function) there is a confirm that is firing as many times as the modal has been opened previously.

let me explain it with my piece of code..

```
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    $('#myModalEditEvent').modal('show');

    $("#deleteEventfromEditModal").click(function () {
                if (!confirm("are you sure?")) {
                    return 0;
                }
                else {
                    var classID = calEvent.id;

                    var deleteRequest = {
                        classID: classID,
                    };

                    var dataString = JSON.stringify(deleteRequest); // parsing the request above. 
                    $.ajax({     // starting an  ajax func 
                        })
                };
            });  
 }
```

this is my html code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalEditEvent" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="EditEventHeader"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="ClassesDDLEdit" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select id="GuidesDDLEdit" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                    <input id="classStartTimeEdit" type="text" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="Start time">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                </div><br />
                <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                    <input id="classEndTimeEdit" type="text" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="start time">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
                </div><br />
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="AddEventAfetEditing" class="btn btn-info center-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEditEvent">Save</button><br />
                    <button type="button" id="deleteEventfromEditModal" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash center-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEditEvent"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what can i do to prevent it from happening?

thanks all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your following line

```
$("#deleteEventfromEditModal").click(function () {
```

as follow

```
$("#deleteEventfromEditModal").unbind( "click" ).click(function () {
```

Because on every click you are binding a click event. Therefore you need to unbind it every time

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
 $("#deleteEventfromEditModal").click(function () {
              ...
 });
```

outside the `eventClick`, and do it in the page load for exemple.

`$(document).ready(function(e){...})`